# nginx + codeigniter configuration not working on CentOS 7?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, digital-ocean

I am new on nginx and try to find the issue on StackOverflow but not found the exact one on forums.
After successful installation of nginx, MySQL and php-fpm I test the php.info that was working fine.

I am moving the CodeIgniter project to the nginx from apache server. I edit the `nginx.conf` file that has code

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  173.249.40.xxx;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/ci;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /ci {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }        

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

it was working fine for `php.info` like my path is `http://173.249.40.xxx/ci/info.php` but not working for CodeIgniter `controller name` like `http://173.249.40.xxx/ci/index.php/Welcome` when called. I try from
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/#
for CodeIgniter application but it also not work for me.
The CodeIgniter application path is `'/usr/share/nginx/html/ci/;'`

Please suggest me something. how can I fix it?

Comment: check on the `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`, and be sure is set to the directory where your code is.

In the example page you linked, it is `root /var/www/codeignitor;`

There is were the index.php or html is located. Let's say, if your code is were you said is your application, then change it to:
`root /usr/share/nginx/html/ci/;`

Comment: I tried that one also not worked. `root /usr/share/nginx/html/ci/;`

Answer (score 1):

The codeigniter has it's own routing mechanism so in order to work you need from web server to pass everything you can't find to the `index.php` not to toss 404 messages.

So try to change your `location / {...}` block to the following:

```
location /ci/ {
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /ci/index.php;
    }
```

The above it's taken from the link in your question.

Comment: I edit the question can you please review now. I am still facing the 404 error.

Comment: can you give your access log data after you apply the change I proposed in my config if its still failing with 404?

Comment: I just remove the `location /ci { }` to `location/ { }` and it work for me.

Comment: yeah it will work too but in case you want to serve sth else from root location you need the tailing `/`  in `/ci/`.